# Workstations on a Windows Network have strange FQDNs in DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2022

I manage a site with around 50 Windows desktop PCs.

On the network is a single domain controller, file server and deployment server all running Windows Server 2022 (up to date).

Recently, I've noticed a number of PCs with strange FQDNs:
[DHCP list of clients with hedani.net FQDNs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSOS0.png)

There is no entry for that domain in DNS, however running nslookup on the DC returns:
[NSLookup of Hedani.net from the DC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD4cL.png)

Here is a list of things I've tried:

- All PCs on-site have recently been rebuilt and only have Office and Sophos AV installed.
- Antivirus has found no malware
- Cleared DNS cache
- Checked DNS config on both the servers and affected clients
- Hostname is correct on the affected clients
- Windows is up to date site-wide
- Deleting the DHCP entry and renewing the IP of the machine does fix the strange FQDN to the networks internal address, however this is a temporary fix.

Comment: Do the clients use any VPN oder are there multiple WLANs? Looks like some clients took a local domain and tried registering them with you (and were successful).

Comment: What DNS Domain Name are you assigning the DHCP clients from your DHCP scope or server options?

Comment: Clients do not use VPN on desktop machines (which are the ones affected), there aren't multiple WLANS. The DNS Domain Name assigned is OrgName.Internal.